# Изменить href ссылки с помощью JavaScript

Tags: php, html, javascript

Приветствую.
Имеется php документ в котором парсятся ссылки с сайта, так вот они выводятся как надо, но при нажатий на них их значения добавляются в конце моего урл, а надо чтобы переходили на сайт.
Так вот как с помощью JavaScript'а изменить значения всех ссылок?
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: покажите образец ссылки. скорей всего js там не понадобится

Comment: <a href="/igrovaya-futbolka-chelsi-domashnyaya-mata-razmer-l-i2209528362.html" class="alleLink iTitle">
<span>Игровая футболка Челси (домашняя) Mata размер L</span>
</a>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

возможно будет проще решить на **php:**

```
$a='<a href="/igrovaya-futbolka-chelsi-domashnyaya-mata-razmer-l-i2209528362.html" class="alleLink iTitle"> <span>Игровая футболка Челси (домашняя) Mata размер L</span> </a>';
echo str_replace('href="','href="http://somesite.ru',$a);
```

либо сразу добавить адрес сайта при выводе, зависит от того в каком виде вы получаете ссылки после парсинга.

**jQuery:**

```
$('a .alleLink .iTitle').each(function(){
$(this).attr('href','http://somesite.ru'+$(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: огромное спасибо! работает!

Comment: > $(this).attr('href','http://somesite.ru'+$(this).attr('href'));

    this.href = 'http://somesite.ru' + this.href;

Может быть так, проще будет? Или у тебя JS нет, только jQuery установлен? :D

Comment: @exec я не знаю где js можно скачать, 3 часа гугла ничего не дали... (

Comment: @FLK, если у тебя `MacOS`, то на него нет, можешь не искать.